# postgres condition trigger missing from clause

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on my table such that it only runs if the 'prepaid' column is true for rows where I've modified the value of the 'points_per_month' column.  I tried this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "fix_usage_trigger" 
AFTER UPDATE OF "points_per_month"
ON "public"."clients"
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (ROW.prepaid)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "fix_prepaid_client_available_usage"();
```

psql is telling me this:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "row"
>   LINE 1: ...r_month" ON "public"."clients" FOR EACH ROW WHEN (ROW.prepai...

Clearly I have no FROM clause there, but I'm not sure why I'd need one, nor where to put it.

Comment: try removing the `ROW.` from `ROW.prepaid`.

Comment: ah, oops, nope. instead, replace `ROW.` with `NEW.`

Comment: Thanks, replacing with NEW.prepaid was exactly what it needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be `when (new.prepaid)`, per David's comment. You can access old and new in the when clause (as in the row before and after the update) much like table aliases. The error message is PG complaining that row is not a known table.

Two additional notes:

- it might need to be `when (old.prepaid or new.prepaid)` if you want to manage billing plan switches -- or another two separate triggers. Conversely, `when (old.prepaid and new.prepaid)` if you do not, and someone might run database queries that might inadvertently fire the trigger and create undesirable state (add a unit test or two).
- the function's name suggest something might be wrong further up in your code flow. You might want to fix that instead, by setting the available usage properly to begin with. Doing so might be more efficient, too.